# PhoneJS w Ripple simulator cannot connect to local node server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ripple, phonejs

I ma trying to test a PhoneJS app with data bound to a local node.js data server ( running at localhost:3000, database MongoDB )
it's running fine in my browser ( Chrome ):

```
$.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/Categories') get correctly the data...
```

Trying now to simulate a mobile device, I am running it via Ripple simulator. The app displays correctly in the simulator, but fails when trying to get the data from the node server....

```
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) https://rippleapi.herokuapp.com/xhr_proxy?tinyhippos_apikey=ABC&tinyhippos_rurl=http%3A//127.0.0.1%3A3000/Categories
```

returning

```
   {
  "code": "ECONNREFUSED",
  "errno": "ECONNREFUSED",
  "syscall": "connect"
   }
```

AM I missing some important parameter ?

here is my server.js :

```
var express = require('express'),
categories = require('./routes/category'),
products = require('./routes/product');

var app = express();

cors = require('./cors');
app.use(cors);

// categories
app.get('/categories/:id', categories.findById);
app.get('/categories', categories.findAll);

// products
app.get('/categories/:id/products', products.findByCategory);
app.get('/products/:id', products.findById);
app.get('/products', products.findAll);

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000...');
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ripple emulator has "Remote cross domain proxy" enabled by default. For localhost connections, disable it in the "Settings" collapsible group (or set to Local, if your service is not [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)-compatible).